# Using Syslog-kafka got some python syntax erro

Tags: python3, syslog

I need to send message to my kafka cluster, I do the same like this https://syslogng-kafka.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
, and `/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/kafka.conf` like

```
destination authlog_to_kafka {
    python(
        class("syslogng_kafka.kafkadriver.KafkaDestination")
            on-error("fallback-to-string")
            options(
                hosts("dev-idms-kafka001-ncl.nfra.io:9092")
                topic("auth-log")
                verbose("True")
                display_stats("True")
                )
    );
};
log {
    source(s_sys);
    destination(authlog_to_kafka);
};
```

got error like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4alJ0.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this python-based Kafka destination, but starting with version 3.21, [syslog-ng has a native C-based Kafka destination](http://support.oneidentity.com/technical-documents/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.21/administration-guide/destination-forward-send-and-store-log-messages/kafka-publishing-messages-to-apache-kafka-c-implementation). You might want to try using that. You can get [packages for recent syslog-ng versions here](https://www.syslog-ng.com/products/open-source-log-management/3rd-party-binaries.aspx).